# ng build works but ng build --prod throws an error

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-cli, angular7, production

I am a student learning Angular by building project. When i do ng build it works but ng build --prod gives an error.

I have tried removing node_modules and then reinstalling it again.

The error says as follows:

> ERROR in ./src/app/app.module.ngfactory.js 41:3371-3377 "export 'ɵa'
>   (imported as 'i12') was not found in '@angular/common'

Here is my package.json file.

```
    "name": "angular-project",
    "version": "0.0.0",
    "scripts": {
        "ng": "ng",
        "build": "ng build",
        "test": "ng test",
        "lint": "ng lint",
        "e2e": "ng e2e"
    },
    "private": true,
    "dependencies": {
        "@angular/animations": "~8.2.0",
        "@angular/cdk": "^8.1.3",
        "@angular/common": "~8.2.0",
        "@angular/compiler": "~8.2.0",
        "@angular/core": "~8.2.0",
        "@angular/forms": "~8.2.0",
        "@angular/platform-browser": "~8.2.0",
        "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~8.2.0",
        "@angular/router": "~8.2.0",
        "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^5.1.0",
        "@types/socket.io-client": "^1.4.32",
        "avatar-name-initials": "^2.0.5",
        "bootstrap": "^4.3.1",
        "express": "^4.17.1",
        "ng2-file-upload": "^1.3.0",
        "path": "^0.12.7",
        "rxjs": "~6.4.0",
        "rxjs-compat": "^6.5.4",
        "socket.io-client": "^2.3.0",
        "sweetalert2": "^8.16.1",
        "time-ago-pipe": "^1.3.2",
        "tslib": "^1.10.0",
        "zone.js": "~0.9.1"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.802.1",
        "@angular/cli": "^8.3.0",
        "@angular/compiler-cli": "^8.2.3",
        "@angular/language-service": "~8.2.0",
        "@types/jasmine": "~3.3.8",
        "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
        "@types/node": "~8.9.4",
        "codelyzer": "^5.0.0",
        "enhanced-resolve": "^3.3.0",
        "jasmine-core": "~3.4.0",
        "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
        "karma": "~4.1.0",
        "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
        "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.1",
        "karma-jasmine": "~2.0.1",
        "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.4.0",
        "protractor": "~5.4.0",
        "ts-node": "~7.0.0",
        "tslint": "~5.15.0",
        "typescript": "~3.5.3"
    }
}
```

Production Configuration

```
                    "configurations": {
                        "production": {
                            "fileReplacements": [{
                                "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                                "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                            }],
                            "optimization": true,
                            "outputHashing": "all",
                            "sourceMap": false,
                            "extractCss": true,
                            "namedChunks": false,
                            "aot": true,
                            "extractLicenses": true,
                            "vendorChunk": false,
                            "buildOptimizer": true,
                            "budgets": [{
                                    "type": "initial",
                                    "maximumWarning": "2mb",
                                    "maximumError": "5mb"
                                },
                                {
                                    "type": "anyComponentStyle",
                                    "maximumWarning": "6kb",
                                    "maximumError": "10kb"
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    }
```

**Note**: If i turn aot and buildOptimizer to false, it works and no error is thrown.

Comment: @LakshanMamalgaha Yes it successfully creates dist folder without any errors

Comment: Then you should look into the production configuration.

Comment: @OlafDietsche i have added production configuration in description.

Comment: Want to try and update Angular to the latest version? `ng update @angular/core @angular/cli`

Comment: And what is the difference to regular (non-prod) build?

Comment: @DanielNetzer I tried that but it introduced breaking changes. I don't want that right now.

Comment: @OlafDietsche I want to reduce size of bundles to boost performance.